# Convert from Formdata object to javascript array

Tags: javascript

Good morning everyone, is there a method in Javascript to convert
from

```
{ 
 Control[0].Eseguito: "true"
 Control[0].Id:"2"
 Control[0].Nota:""
 Control[1].Eseguito: "true"
 Control[1].Id:"2"
 Control[1].Nota:""
}
```

to javascript Array?

```
Control: Array(2)
0: {Id: '1', Eseguito: "true", Nota: ''}
1: {Id: '1', Eseguito: "true", Nota: ''}
```

EDIT

```
let myForm = document.getElementById('ControlForm');
var Controls = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(myForm).entries());
```

In mine ExecControl.cshtml i have situation like this, this is only a small snippet of codes

```
@{
    int Indice = 0;
}

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListControls.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Model.ListControls[i].Controls.Length; j++)
    {
        ...
        <input type="text" style="width:100%;" name="Control[@Indice].Nota"/>
        input type="text" style="width:100%;" name="Control[@Indice].Id" value="@ListControls[i].Controls.Id"/>
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: which form are you using? angular forms?

Comment: No, i use the classic html form

Comment: Can you post the code how you are generating `Control` details from an HTML form?

Comment: What is the content is `Controls` at the moment? Your first code block is unclear, is `Control[0].Eseguito` supposed to be keys in an object? So you actually have: `{"Control[0].Eseguito": "true", ... }`

Comment: @Nitheesh, just added. Then in my view i have input type with name like "Controls[@Indice].Eseguito"

Comment: @MrBuffalo Please post the relavent HTML code aswell

Comment: @NickParsons Yeah is the key, I didn't specify, forgive me

Comment: @Nitheesh i added small snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert only [index] type data to array with this method.

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("Control[0].Id",1);formData.append("Control[0].Nota","Notaval");formData.append("Control[1].Id",2);formData.append("Control[1].Nota","Nott");


function toArray(data){
  var result = [];
  for (const [key,value] of data.entries()) {
      if(!key.includes("[") || !key.includes("]")) {return;}
      var indexVal =  key.indexOf("[") + 1;
      var indexVal2 =  key.indexOf("]");
      var index = parseInt(key.substring(indexVal,indexVal2))
      if(index == NaN){ return;}
      var field = key.split(".")[1]
      result[index] = {...result[index],[field]:value}
    }
   return result;
}
 console.log(toArray(formData));
```